# Manipulate the session history with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, url, browser, browser-history

I need to delete the latest browser history entry for [this reason](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/821359/reload-an-iframe-without-adding-to-the-history), but any other functions exposed by JS that manipulate (add/remove) history entries for the current page/tab, are also welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you use location.replace on the IFrame?

Answer (score 1):

I highly doubt that there is a way. The `window.history` object provides read-only access to the browsing history for security reasons.

Answer (score 1):

That cannot be done using javascript ( within normal parameters that is, you could try exploiting a browser bug and such but i doubt that is the idea here)