# How does Facebook post json and load the response in an iframe?

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, forms, iframe

I have the exact same use case as Facebook for Apps/Games embedded on their canvas page [explained here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/games/canvas/#canvas). I want to send an HTTP POST request containing a JSON object to an externally hosted site, and load the response in an `iframe`, as [described here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/appsonfacebook/tutorial/#auth).

So far, I've tried the following:

- POSTing with a `form`, using the `target` attribute to load the result in an iframe. The fields of the `form` are not JSON here (and if I try to convert them, I'll have to send a POST request manually, with the problem explained by the next bullet point)
- POSTing JSON manually, e.g. with jQuery's `$.ajax()` or `$.post()`, but then I cannot make the response load in my `iframe`. And if I try to insert it into the DOM manually with jQuery, obviously relative links won't work.
- Setting the `src` property on the `iframe`, but this only allows for GET requests.

As you can see, I only manage to get at most 2 of the 3 desired properties. Does anyone know how to do it (or how Facebook does it)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case anyone comes across the same problem, this is what I found:

According to [this](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/appsonfacebook/tutorial/#auth), Facebook most probably does the following: they submit a (hidden) `form` with a single parameter with the name "signed_request" and the complete JSON Object encoded as a Base64 string. With the help of the `target` attribute of the `form`, the response gets loaded into the `iframe` automatically. The `form` can also be created dynamically, and inserted into the DOM with the help of, for example, jQuery.

Another solution would work as follows: Start by sending an AJAX request with JSON data to the external site. The site then constructs the response, caches it and replies with the URL where the response can be loaded. The `src` attribute of the `iframe` is then set to this URL, which loads the original response with an HTTP GET request.

I used the second approach, as I have to submit several requests with dynamically changing data, and do not want to edit the DOM each time. I also used the advice from [this stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8681618/2810249) to not leave a browser history entry when loading the response in my `iframe`.