# history.replaceState issue with iframes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe, history

I am going nuts over this. I have read every thing I could find on the subject but I am lost...

I have a page with a button and 2 iframes.

```
<input name="showButton" type="button" id="showButton" value="Show" />
<iframe id="messagelistviewframe" src="blank.html"></iframe>
<iframe id="messageviewframe" src="blank.html"></iframe>
```

Clicking the button changes the url of the 2 iframes.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#showButton').bind("click", function (e) {
        $('#messagelistviewframe').attr('src', 'red.html');
        $('#messageviewframe').attr('src', 'yellow.html');
    });    
}
```

Unfortunately this creates 2 history entries, one for each iframe url change. So clicking the browser's back button, I get first a page with the 2nd iframe back to its original url and if I click again I get both.

I have tried history.replaceState in all possible ways I believe to no avail. I got some results with Firefox but not Chrome nor IE.

Is there a way to get the back button to directly give me my original page with the original iframe urls? TIA

Answer (score 4):

Finally found the answer in this article [Reload an IFRAME without adding to the history](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/821359/reload-an-iframe-without-adding-to-the-history). The trick is to recreate the iframe or to remove it from the DOM and re-add it.