# Azure AD Easy Auth expires with CORS Error

Tags: authentication, oauth-2.0, azure-web-app-service, azure-active-directory

Question is linked to [Azure AD Easy Auth expires even when users are actively using application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45819990/azure-ad-easy-auth-expires-even-when-users-are-actively-using-application/48952000#48952000). Based on explanation shared it seems Easy Auth mechanism is not the right fit for SPA hosted on Azure Web Apps?
Can MS add mentioned options under official documentation -
 "https://learn.microsoft.com/en-in/azure/app-service/app-service-authentication-overview?toc=%2fazure%2fapp-service-web%2ftoc.json"

I am facing the following issue:
 when AppServiceAuthSession cookie expires, any SPA AJAX requests to underlying secure API Calls fails with CORS issue :Failed to load https://login.windows.net//oauth2/authorize?response_type=code+id_token&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fapp.contoso.com%2F.auth%2Flogin%2Faad%2Fcallback&client_id=xxxxx&scope=openid+profile+email&response_mode=form_post&nonce=xxxxx&state=redir%3D%252Fapi%252Fv2%252Fget-dataapi: Redirect from 'https://login.windows.net/xxxxxxxxxxxx/oauth2/authorize?response_type=code+id_token&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%app.contoso.com%2F.auth%2Flogin%2Faad%2Fcallback&client_id=xxxxx&scope=openid+profile+email&response_mode=form_post&nonce=xxxx&state=redir%3D%252Fapi%252Fv2%252Fget-dataapi' to 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/xxxxxxxxxx/oauth2/authorize?response_type=code+id_token&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%app.contoso.com%2F.auth%2Flogin%2Faad%2Fcallback&client_id=xxxxxxxxxx&scope=openid+profile+email&response_mode=form_post&nonce=xxxxxxxxxxx&state=redir%3D%252Fapi%252Fv2%252Fget-dataapi' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'https://app.contoso.com' is therefore not allowed access. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

Comment: Yeah so it is trying to redirect you to re-auth but that doesn't really work with AJAX calls :) Easy Auth might not be a good fit for SPAs like you said, might have to implement auth in the front-end with ADAL.JS.

Answer (score 0):

> I am facing the following issue: when AppServiceAuthSession cookie expires, any SPA AJAX requests to underlying secure API Calls fails with CORS issue

Per my understanding, you are using the build-in App Service Authentication / Authorization (EasyAuth) feature with your SPA without writing any code or using client library for authentication in your SPA.

For Ajax request with the invalid cookie or token, I could encounter the similar issue as follows:

[image]

At this time, you could capture the Ajax error and redirect your SPA for re-authenticate to retrieve the new AppServiceAuthSession cookie.

Chris Gillum's answer in 
[Azure AD Easy Auth expires even when users are actively using application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45819990/azure-ad-easy-auth-expires-even-when-users-are-actively-using-application/48952000#48952000)
 could fit your scenario.

Based on my experience, you could use the [JavaScript client library for Azure Mobile Apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-mobile/app-service-mobile-html-how-to-use-client-library) in your SPA for retrieving the `x-zumo-auth` token and use the token approach as Chris Gillum answered. For a simple way, you could use the server-flow authentication as follows:

```html
client.login("aad").done(function (results) {
     alert("You are now logged in as: " + results.userId);
     console.log("x-zumo-auth token is: "+ results.mobileServiceAuthenticationToken);
}, function (err) {
     alert("Error: " + err);
});
```

Also, you could directly retrieving the AAD id_token or access_token via using [Active Directory Authentication Library (ADAL) for JavaScript](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-js) as juunas commented, then include the token (id_token, access_token) in the Authorization header as a bearer token to request your WebAPIs.

Additionally, you could use the client-flow authentication for App Service, and retrieve the id_token or access_token via ADAL.js, then use the previous token to login with EasyAuth for retrieving the `AuthenticationToken` as the `x-zumo-token`, then use the `x-zumo-token` to request your WebAPIs.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your comments. So, all above-mentioned methods are fixes to overcome the shortcoming of Easy Auth.

Comment: Per my understanding, the server-flow authentication of App Service Authentication (EasyAuth) is not suitable for SPA, you could use the client-flow authentication, you use ADAL.js to retrieve the id_token or access_token of AAD, then use the previous token as the bearer token to request your WebAPI endpoints.

Comment: Also, you could post a request  to `https://{your-app-name}.azurewebsites.net/.auth/login/aad` with the payload `{"access_token":"the-aad-accessToken"}` for retrieving the `authenticationToken`. then send request to WebAPI endpoints with the header `x-zumo-auth` value to the `authenticationToken`. At this point, you need to manage the token in your SPA client.

Comment: Moreover, you could follow [Authenticate users](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-mobile/app-service-mobile-dotnet-how-to-use-client-library#authentication) to understand the client-flow and server-flow authentication for App Service Authentication.

Comment: Yes. We have to go down that route only and not to rely on EasyAuth any more